# Newtonsoft JObject.Parse throws base Exception...how to handle

Tags: c#, json.net

Using Newtonsoft Json.NET 6.0.8 and I have code like this:

```
public bool ValidateSchema<T>(T model, out IList<string> messages)
{
        string stringedObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
            });

        messages = new List<string>();
        JObject objectToValidate;
        try
        {
            objectToValidate = JObject.Parse(stringedObject);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            messages.Add("Unable to parse jsonObject.");
            return false;
        }

        JsonSchema schema = JsonSchemaRepository.SchemaDictionary[typeof(T)];

        return objectToValidate.IsValid(schema, out messages);
}
```

Specifically the try catch block. From my reading it seems this method only throws the base exception which I don't really want to catch as it could hide all sorts of other important errors.

Now the Json.NET nuget package is very professional so I have to wonder if I am implementing my parse method incorrectly or any other ideas on how I can handle parse errors.

perhaps log and rethrow?

TIA

Comment: Their own `Parse()` method shouldn't throw other important errors.  But you're right; this is poor code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137

Comment: Exactly right. I am taking over an existing project and I implemented some code analysis rules and this showed up.

Comment: 1) Do you actually know that an exception other than [`JsonException`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonException.htm) is being thrown?  2) I believe it's possible to force Json.NET to create invalid JSON by [writing raw data](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeRawJson.htm).  Without the equivalent converters on read, parsing might, in theory, throw a `JsonException`.

Comment: Json.NET doesn't (intentionally) throw `System.Exception`.  It throws exceptions of type (or subclasses of type) [`JsonException`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonException.htm).  For instance, in the source code for [`JObject`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs) you can see [`JsonReaderException`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReaderException.htm) being thrown.  If it ever throws a raw `Exception`, it's probably a bug in Json.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch the base Exception, then rethrow it if it's a subclass of Exception.

```
try
{
    objectToValidate = JObject.Parse(stringedObject);      
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Exception)))
        throw;

    //Handle the case when e is the base Exception
    messages.Add("Unable to parse jsonObject.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh excellent. That will work! Thank you for the great idea.

Comment: Use `throw;` instead, then you wont lose the stacktrace.